# Изменение цвета при переходе между двумя div

Tags: html, css

Вопрос в там, как можно осуществить такой переход? 
Вариант с mix-blend-mode difference не подходит, так как будет смешение и с синим цветом, а задача конкретно в переходе между двумя цветами (белый и чёрный вариант).

[image: Пример перехода]

Comment: в голову приходит только дублирование всего блока

Comment: В случае дублирования всё равно не получится так идеально менять z-index при переходе. Будет резкая смена одного на другое.

Comment: менять не z-index, a height у элемента сверху (с overflow)

Comment: Хм, вполне может сработать, сейчас попробую.